# iOS app for simultaneous reading and listening to a (audio) book

Tags: ios, ebook, audiobook

**I'd like to read books in a foreign language while listening to its Audiobook version. Is there an app that can do that?**

Notes:

- This is what Amazon calls **Immersive Reading**. It's available on their Kindle Fire tablets.
- A plus would be if I could tap a word to see its translation.
- It does not so much matter what books are available. I'm happy as long as there are some Public Domain books.

Answer (score 1):

If I got that correctly I think [Audible Whispersync](http://audible.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4146/~/whispersync-for-voice-%26-immersion-reading) (an Amazon product) does that.

Comment: (Shame on you if it is because it's the 2nd result when google'ing "immersive reading kindle" ;-) .)

Comment: Seems you're right. I knew about Amazon Immersive Reading (and Whispersync), but I read somewhere that they don't offer it on iOS devices. Gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're tech-savvy and have DRM-free EPUB and audiobook versions of your book, you can use the free [Storyteller](https://smoores.gitlab.io/storyteller/) server software and iOS app to sync the EPUB to the audiobook and listen to it while reading it as it highlights the currently-read text.